# How to fix position on LinearLayout items after setting visibility?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linearLayout that contains two FrameLayout. I set the visibility to one of them to *GONE* when I do Landscape mode. And when I return to portrait mode I set the visibility to *VISIBLE* . I'm using *GONE* because I don't want the reserved place of the invisible element.

***Result:***

When returning to portrait mode, the two FrameLayout change positions.

***Cases:***

- When I select the first frameLayout to pass to landscape, the second one change position.
- When I select the second frameLayout to pass to landscape, the first one change position.

Comment: post your source code where you visible or gone layouts

Comment: I just do frame1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); frame2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

I can't post the code where I set because it's too long, and it's in different places. isn't related in the XML ?

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mcve] example that demonstrates what you're seeing.

Comment: @risefire post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer. You saved me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use constraintlayout insted of linearlayout and put guidlines

Answer (score -1):

This is from the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility):

> GONE: Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.

So, when you set the FrameLayout visible again is as if you add it again and it takes the last position.

I recommend you to remove and add the view instead of making it visible and gone.
When you add it, use the `addView` method with the index parameter to make it take first position:

```
 linearLayout.addView(frameLayout,0);
```